# How to debug a Azure Stack app service webfarm deployment failed due timeout?

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-stack

I have app service installed on a Azure Stack Development Toolkit. When try to deploy an app, a Django app from a template, for instance, after a few hours I get the message:

```
{ "id": "/subscriptions/e2b6fc4e-ba85-44cb-b284-4dab48af8347/resourceGroups/rg-app-django01/providers/Microsoft.Resources/deployments/PTVS.Djangoa566d356-ae09/operations/5103DB5E6F50B0C9", "operationId": "5103DB5E6F50B0C9", "properties": { "provisioningOperation": "Create", "provisioningState": "Failed", "timestamp": "2020-06-26T04:46:25.7794853Z", "duration": "PT2H8.3898363S", "trackingId": "4e075a22-309c-42e5-98ad-712f68c32b19", "statusCode": "RequestTimeout", "statusMessage": { "error": { "code": "ResourceDeploymentFailure", "message": "The resource provision operation did not complete within the allowed timeout period. Please see https://aka.ms/arm-deploy for usage details." } }, "targetResource": { "id": "/subscriptions/e2b6fc4e-ba85-44cb-b284-4dab48af8347/resourceGroups/rg-app-django01/providers/Microsoft.Web/serverfarms/app-sp-django01", "resourceType": "Microsoft.Web/serverfarms", "resourceName": "app-sp-django01" } }}
```

I suspect it's due to permissions or a network access issue, but I don't know how to proceed.

Comment: raise a support  ticket

Comment: thank you, no MS support for ASDK

Comment: I don't think there's enough information provided. You only shared a single error message, related to a provisioning timeout. Please consider editing your question to contain more details. As is, we know nothing about your environment, your app, etc.

Comment: It's the only info a have. My ASDK works fine running VMs, and we are trying to test apps now. I ran the app services install package successfully. But when I try to deploy my first web app from a custom template, I get this timeout message. ASDK is not supported by MS, they're only supporting Azure Stack production environments. Maybe it's just a silly error, and someone went through this before, thank you!